# How can we make a form url valid for 48 hrs in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on a button how can we create a dynamic form url with below fields using react hooks and url globally valid only for 48 hrs.

`https://localhost/aB123GHedFGH138HGxYz/recommendform`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
      // nominee text field
      // description
      // nominatedby
      // save button
      // cancel button
  const [createForm, setCreateForm] = useState([
    { nominee: "", description: "", nominatedby: "" }
  ]);

  const inputForm = (choiceForm) => {
    alert("Hello");
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Form</h1>
      <form>
        {createForm.map((field, index) => {
          <div key={index}>
            <input name="nominee" type="text" />
          </div>;
        })}
        <input value="Create Form" type="button" onClick={inputForm} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wilson-hmts5?file=/src/App.js:0-311

Comment: This question is not well defined: 48hrs per user, globally, persist after refresh? What have you tried? What didn't work on your attempt?

Comment: Yes globally valid for 48 hrs, not per user.

Comment: I have updated my question, I am not sure how do I add fields and provide as a dynamic link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a form as you asked.

Adding 48h limit globally (meaning it should persist for all users) requires a server, then you will just need to fetch/update the status. See [API and AJAX calls in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

```
const formFields = [
  ["nominee", "Example"],
  ["description", "Desc"],
  ["nominatedby", ""]
];

export default function App() {
  const [isFormCreated, setIsFormCreated] = useState(false);

  const onClickEnableForm = () => setIsFormCreated(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Form</h1>
      {isFormCreated && (
        <form>
          {formFields.map(([name, value]) => {
            return (
              <div key={name}>
                <input defaultValue={value} name={name} type="text" />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      )}
      {!isFormCreated && (
        <input value="Create Form" type="button" onClick={onClickEnableForm} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit recursing-mendel-ywjmh]

Comment: Appreciate your reply Dennis, how do I pass the created dynamic form as a url ? Does it need a server as well ?

Comment: You will need to make the form in a designated route, see `react-route-dom`, and then you can share the url from there